# How can I print a specific two-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
<?php
$multiplicand=1;
for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++)
{
  $product[$i][$multiplicand] = $multiplicand*$i;
}
```

I'm supposed to correct the size of the array to 231 by 537 and I have to access to [167][31]. The funny thing is that my lecturer said that the table should start from 0. Please help me to do the necessary arrangement/ correction.

Comment: You need to mark this with the homework tag if this is for a class.

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag. [It's been deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: I stand corrected. Need to keep up with the times!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another loop inside the one you have now. Then you can start from 0 0 and go to 231 537. Just let both start from 0 ($i = 0, $j = 0) and go to 231 and 537 ($i < 231, $j < 537).

Also you need to google 2D array

Comment: could you help me to re-write the whole code? Thank!

Comment: I just did. I won't write your code for you though. If I do that then you wouldnt learn anything. Like I said, google 2D array and you will find plenty of info on how to do it.